# Can I mine with an E5 2620 CPU?

Tags: litecoin, mining-profitability, cpu

I plan on mining [litecoins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litecoin), but I'm somewhat late and new into the game. Would it be better for me to get a video card later, tight on budget?

I'm not sure how to do the math. There isn't any overhead costs; I just want to build and let it run. I can build three rigs, all with 2 x [E5 2620](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_2011#Server_.28Xeon_E5-16xx.2F26xx.29) and 32 GB RAM. How much would I produce per day?

Comment: *Can I mine...?* Yes. *How much...?* Build one, see how it goes and multiply by three.

Comment: But I don't know how the hash math thing works. If you can give me an answer for one. I can multiply by 3. :)

Comment: See my answer.  You will get horrible results.  CPU are not made for mining I cannot even get my i7-3770 to mine.  I have to have cgminer use my GPU.

Comment: The only coins you can mine nowadays using *any* CPU, no matter how fast, are those using algorithms specifically designed to be GPU- or ASIC- unfriendly, such as primecoin (search of primes), quarkcoin (several hashes in row), etc. Anything else, and you'd only lose money - unless you're doing it just for fun.

Answer (score 1):

Using a CPU is a bad idea; a GPU is better. Good AMD...  The best AMDs are hard to find or impossible to find, but the AMD R9 280x and 290x you can find (second-hand on eBay if you don't see them on [Newegg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newegg), etc..) Sort the chart by GPU, or in your case CPU, search for your CPU...

I tried to play with mining with an i7-3770, and it wouldn't. I don't have any idea why. I had to tell [CGMiner](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/CGMiner) to use my GPU which is NOT an AMD, thus horrible. I could mine [Coinye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coinye) coins, but who cares about that.

The page *[Mining hardware comparison](https://litecoin.info/Mining_hardware_comparison)* is great for your question.

Comment: If an i5 yields about 0.3 Primecoins a week, with an i7 I suspect you could get 50% more. Since you need the whole PC to be on so the GPU can work, the extra cost of putting the CPU at 100% instead of idle would be almost negligible.

Comment: i don't advise using CPU,  and if a good GPU is being pushed... you NEED to have open rig with fans blowing on them. In a case, you will burn them up.

Comment: Primecoins are only mineable with CPU - some experimental GPU miners exist, but they're less productive (and thus, profitable) than CPUs. Quarkcoins are CPU-only mineable as well. My point is: having the CPU at 100% won't add much electric consumption or heat vs. what the GPU is already consuming, but do can add for the final profit.

Comment: My fault I didn't know that about Prime until now , thx Joe

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this hardware comparison](https://litecoin.info/Mining_hardware_comparison#Intel)

1 CPU ~ 50 KH/s

3 rigs x 2 CPU x 50 KH/s each ~ 300 KH/s

At the moment, according to the [coinwars](http://www.coinwarz.com/calculators/litecoin-mining-calculator/?h=300&p=1000.00&pc=0.10&pf=0.00&d=3931.59487261&r=50.00000000&er=0.02929000&hc=0.00), you would mine $9.75 a month or $0.33 a day.

Answer (score -2):

Better mine new alt coin and then convert them into litecoin that will be more convenient. Have a look on coinchoose.com to select a coin with less difficulty and which website is trading them.

Comment: He'd lose money mining any scrypt-based SHA-256-based coin. CPUs are only good for primecoin, quarkcoin, protoshares and a few others, no more.

Comment: Agree with mine new alt coin and convert to litecoin, but not with the OP CPU

Comment: Khan: the original poster is asking specifically about mining with CPU only for he lacks a GPU and is tight on money to buy one.